# Missing header files when installing

Tags: apt, upgrade, mysql

I am trying to install `Mysql-5.5` directly through Terminal but I get an `header files is missing`error and it fails to install.

The problem stays when I run `sudo apt-get update/upgrade`

Is ther any way around this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-source-5.5 mysql-testsuite mysql-testsuite-5.5
```